# ioslides with latex package

Tags: r-markdown, ioslides

I want to use a latex command \fint in ioslides. That commond is included in a Latex package "esint". I used the following code in Rmarkdown to include that package. It seems it does not work.

```
header-includes:
   - \usepackage{esint}
output:
  ioslides_presentation
```

Is it true that in R presentation, one can not use Latex package? If so, is there anyway to get around to use \fint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MathJax is not LaTeX: it handles input similar to LaTeX but the way it operates under the hood is completely different: MathJax only implements prominent math mode LaTeX macros using Javascript. Most of the features used by LaTeX packages are missing, which means that you cannot simply 'load' a LaTeX package into ioslides (or any other Rmarkdown project with HTML output) and expect it to work.

I think the closest you can get is with a strikethrough macros, e.g. the one provided with the MathJax extension [enclose](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/input/tex/extensions/enclose.html). This looks halfway decent:

```latex
\begin{align}
  \require{enclose}
  \enclose{horizontalstrike}{\int} = \frac{1}{b-a}\int_a^b f(x) \mathrm{d}x
\end{align}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I put your code in my slides with $$ sign wrapping about it. However, it does not display very well. The console says Loading required package: MendelianRandomization
Error in .requirePackage(package) : 
  unable to find required package ‘MendelianRandomization’

Comment: [MendelianRandomization](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/MendelianRandomization/MendelianRandomization.pdf) is an R package (which seems not to be installed). This error is caused by an attempt to load the package. I suggest you run `install.packages("MendelianRandomization")`. However, this error has nothing to do with math not being displayed well by a browser. I suggest you use an `align` environment as shown in my answer for display style and `\(` ... `\)` for inline formulas.

Comment: I tried your method and updated my RStudio in order to have the right display in a browser. It is solved now. Thank you for your answer! You are so kind.

Comment: You're welcome. Would be great if you would accept my answer. (: